# Is $\exists y\forall x(Pxy\land Qy)$ always false?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Is $\exists y\forall x(Pxy\land Qy)$ always false? I ask because of the following:

1. Let the domain of discourse be the set where x and y are natural numbers and y is always greater than x.
2. Let P be the set of Prime Numbers
3. $\exists x\exists y\left(y>x\land y\in P\right)\rightarrow\exists y\forall x\left(y>x\rightarrow y\in P\right)$ is valid. Also, $\exists x\exists y\left(y>x\land y\in P\right)$ is true. Thus, $\exists y\forall x(y>x\rightarrow y\in P)$ is true.
4. $\forall x\forall y(y>x)\land\exists y\forall x(y>x\rightarrow y\in P)\rightarrow\exists y\forall x(y>x\land y\in P)$ is valid.
5. However, $\exists y\forall x(y>x\land y\in P)$ seems false. Yet, $\forall x\forall y(y>x)$ and $\forall x\exists y(y>x\rightarrow y\in P)$ are true.
6. Thus, it must be the case that $\exists y\forall x(y>x\land y\in P)$ is true.

Comment: Please clarify what question you're asking. The title/first line of the post is a very different question from the last line of the post. (Also $P$ is being used for two different things, which is confusing.) The first asserted implication, "$\exists x\exists y\left(y>x\land y\in P\right)\rightarrow\exists y\forall x\left(y>x\rightarrow y\in P\right)$ is valid", certainly doesn't seem valid to me as a logical deduction.

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. How could $\exists y\forall x(Pxy\land Qy)$ be necessarily false if $P$ and $Q$ are allowed to be anything? $P$ and $Q$ could be true on all inputs...

Comment: @GregMartin, the title is using P as a predicate. The content is a universal instantiation of the title. Also, the content is valid. As proof of this, see the following link: <https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~7x~7y(Pxy~1Qy)~5~6x~7y(Pxy~5Qy)>

Comment: Why are you saying $\forall x \forall y (y>x)$ is true?

Comment: Because I can specify whatever the domain of discourse is and the domain of discourse was defined with y always being greater than x.

Comment: If multiple people see this standard notation and comment that it's clearly not valid as written, and the OP has a special interpretation of that notation or unstated clarifications, then the OP should put all relevant information into the post itself. Until then, there's no point in expecting helpful feedback.